# How to access a MySQL database webservice over LAN?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, lan

I have three PCs that I connect over LAN.

- The first PC to database;
- The second to web service CodeIgniter RESTful;
- The third to client.

Now how can I connect web service CodeIgniter server to database, I've set the IP on **aplication/config/database.php**,

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

I've changed `localhost` with the IP that is used by the first pc:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '192.168.1.10';
```

But, the result :

> A database error occurred
>   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: not yet,
is that take affect ??.

how i do it ?
can you explain...
*i`m newbie one

Comment: did you try connecting from the command line using the same settings? e.g. `mysql -u username -h 192.168.1.10 -p`? If that doesn't work, then you've got the wrong settings.

Comment: @vhu: if it was permissions, then the error would be "access denied", not "unable to connect"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A database error occurred
>   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

If this is MySQL, networking of the database server is not enabled by default. To enable networking in MySQL you need to find the active MySQL configuration file named `my.cnf`. And edit it.

I am going to explain how to do this on Ubuntu 12.04, but the instructions are similar for most any Linux install.

**Enable MySQL Networking**

First, open the file using an editor like `nano`. You might need to run the command via `sudo`:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then look for the area in your configuration file with the `bind-address` option:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Now change that `bind-address` setting to the following:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

With that done save the file & restart MySQL like this:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And now your MySQL database will be able to take non-localhost connections from remote machines.

**Make Sure the MySQL Port `3306` is Open**

That said, even with networking enabled, you should still check if you are able to connect to the remote machine from the command line using a networking tool such as `nmap`. You might have a firewall on `192.168.1.10` blocking MySQL port `3306` so you need to check if it is open or closed like this:

```
nmap 192.168.1.10 -p3306
```

And if port `3306` is open, this will be the response; note the `open` under `STATE`:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-10 10:34 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
Host is up (0.0035s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

But if port `3306` is closed, you will get this; note the `closed` under `STATE`:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-10 10:34 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
Host is up (0.0035s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql
```

**Check Your MySQL User Grants**

Now with that all done, your MySQL database server should be accessible on the network. But that said, you need to make sure your database user you are using is allowed to connect from a remote machine on your LAN.  So login to MySQL & run this command to see what grants the user might have:

```
SELECT user, host FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

This will show you a list of users & hosts connected to those users in MySQL. The thing is most users are only granted access privileges to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Some are granted the wildcard host of `%`. You need to look at that list and see if the user you want to use has a wildcard host (`%`) or a specific IP address connected to them. You can check a user’s `GRANT`s by running a line like this; of course change `[your_database_user]` and `[hostname]` to match your settings:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR '[your_database_user]'@'[hostname]';
```

That should show you a list of available `GRANT`s for a user on a specific host. If they have `GRANT`s that would allow remote access—such as using wildcard `%` host—then you are all set. If they don’t have any `GRANT`s you can run the following MySQL commands; of course change `[your_database]` and `[your_database_user]` to match your settings:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `[your_database]`.* TO '[your_database_user]'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `[your_database]`.* TO '[your_database_user]'@'10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Both `GRANT` lines apply a fairly standard set of access rights to a database. The first line applies them to any connection in the LAN network range of `192.168.x.x`. The second line applies them to any connection in the LAN network range of `10.x.x.x`. I like to do that to cover all bases on internal networks.  The last `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` line basically tells MySQL to reload the user privileges tables which allow those grants to take effect.