# Wordpress: MySQL Database and UNC Share

Tags: mysql, database, windows, wordpress, server

I am about to install WordPress on a Windows 2008 server - two load balanced servers with a UNC share. Web browsing using the server is out of the question (IT security policy) so using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer is also a non starter. I will therefore have to install it manually.

So far I have installed PHP (routine), but I now need to install MySQL and create a database. However, with these being two separate servers, what effect is this going to have on the database - will this require a database on each server? Will they remain in sync? Can the database itself be put in the UNC share?

In short, can anyone advise me whether this is possible and how to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: It would be best to have the database on a separate 3rd server in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL and create the database on the server which is supposed to have it - preferably a 3rd one or on the UNC. In the MySQL config, enable network connections via [`my.cnf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24143695/1431750), specifically the `bind-address`.

Both the PHP boxes should connect to that one MySQL db (using it's LAN ip address). (And yes, they would remain in sync since they connect to the same db.)