Django OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available
I am encountering an issue while trying to connect my Django project to a MySQL database hosted on cPanel using "mysql-connector-python". Despite configuring the settings correctly, I consistently receive an OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available when attempting to run my Django application.
Database Settings in settings.py:
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': 'the name',       
    'USER': 'the user',      
    'PASSWORD': 'the pass',  
    'HOST': 'localhost',                
    'PORT': '3306',                     
    }
}

I am using mysql-connector-python version 8.4.0 to connect to the MySQL database.
Verified database credentials and ensured they match those configured in cPanel.
Checked MySQL server status and confirmed it is running without issues.
Error Message: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (-1, 'MySQL Connection not available.', None)
The Django application and MySQL database are hosted on separate servers, with cPanel managing the MySQL instance. The MySQL user has been granted all privileges (ALL PRIVILEGES) for the specified database.

usually a mysql server are configured only to allow localhost access, so oyu need to read up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143252/how-to-access-a-mysql-database-webservice-over-lan

@nbk My Django project is running on localhost (my PC) as well. The issue arises when I try to connect it to the MySQL database hosted on cPanel. The Django project works fine on localhost, but when I attempt to establish a connection to the MySQL database, I encounter the error

the connection s from your pc to mysql over internet which is not localhost
